# Will the columns containing leading ones in an RREF matrix always span the same space as the corresponding columns in the original matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been self-studying linear algebra and this question came up in my mind:

> Will the columns containing leading ones in an RREF matrix always span the same space as the corresponding columns in the original matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Both row exchange and row replacement will alter the span of columns. For row exchange, consider the example:

\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

For row replacement, consider the example:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}